# MetroFramework - MetroMenuStrip and probably some more are missing from a Toolbox menu

Tags: c#, winforms, java-metro-framework, visual-studio-community

I just tried to install this framework through the Visual Studio Community's NuGet and I linked appropriate dll, so this is what I got:

[image: Toolbox menu]

Still, things like MetroContextMenu or MentroMenuStrip are missing...Probably some more that I am not aware of.

What would be the correct way to install this framework? What am I missing?

I am using Visual Studio Community and a Winforms based application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you ended up having the controls that are found in [this repository](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework/tree/master/MetroFramework/Controls)

The original guy must have removed a number of controls due to some bugs and issues, though i dont think so that there was a MetroMenuStrip provided.

You are missing some more controls like :

1. MetroGrid
2. MetroDateTime

If you want to get those controls as well, [here is the link](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui/tree/master/MetroFramework/Controls) to a repo someone has been maintaining.

I dont think so that you will get a MetroMenuStrip or maybe you can go through the Git history and check to see if they had the source code back in time.

If you want to create your [Custom MetroMenuStrip](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=614673&av=898829), This guy has done something similar.

Best of luck.

Comment: Ah okay... I thought I saw on the internet some youtube tutorials with menu strip control... Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way, do I install this package aside with the current one? Or should I remove the current one first?

Comment: Remove the current one and get a copy of this package, there are 3 interlinked libraries. So better to have a fresh copy